# How to Remove this Black Bar which appears Below Excel Worksheet on my website

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

How do I remove this black bar after I embed an Excel worksheet on my website?

[image: Black Bar after Embedding Excel Worksheet on my website]

Embedding Code :

```
<iframe width="517" height="432" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=7A5AABE4C00398339&resid=7A5AABE4C0038339%21115&authkey=AGE4mfckXu07zQ&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&AllowTyping=True&Item='Sheet2'!G3%3AN22&wdDownloadButton=True"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this worksheet is loaded from OneDrive, for security reasons, you cannot modify the `iframe`. You can cover the bottom bar with instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24069050/how-to-hide-cover-a-certain-part-of-an-iframe). If you want to try injecting JavaScript to remove the bar (probably won't work), then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194398/inject-a-javascript-function-into-an-iframe).